# How to get mpif90 compiler for OpenSUSE Leap 15.0?

Tags: fortran, mpi, fortran90, opensuse

I want to run a program on OpenSUSE Leap 15.0, and I must compile it with the Fortran90 compiler mpif90 first. Unfortunately I can not find mpif90 for the respective distro. Is there a way to install it?

Comment: Take a look here: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries - if you can survive with source based installation, take a look here: http://www.owsiak.org/running-open-mpi-on-macos/ - I know it's for macOS, but steps will be nearly the same for Linux based distro.

Answer (score 3):

You will need the package `openmpi3-devel`:

```
sudo zypper install openmpi3-devel
```

Note that, to allow co-existence of several Open MPI major versions, the binaries (including `mpif90`) do not go into `/usr/bin`, but into `/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi3/bin`. A recommended way to work with MPI is to source the environment script

```
. /usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi3/bin/mpivars.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

From the package repositories, install an MPI implementation such as Open MPI (I don't use OpenSUSE myself so I don't know what the name of the package is, but I'm sure you'll find it if you use the search functionality of the package manager). That will install the compiler wrappers like mpicc, mpifort, mpif90 and so on.

**Edit**: The compiler wrappers might be in a -dev or -devel package. On Ubuntu 18.04 the openmpi compiler wrappers are found in the package "libopenmpi-dev".

Comment: `mpif90` might be provided by the devel package.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: Good point. I just checked, and at least on Ubuntu that is indeed the case.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the normal `/usr/lib64/mpi` location OpenSUSE also features the HPC project/environment with several types of MPI libraries and their versions and compilers used using the module system.

Install the package `openmpi3-gnu-hpc-devel` and enable it using

```
module load gnu
module load openmpi
```

Using the latter may suffice.

Then you can also install many associated libraries like FFTW3 or HDF5 and use them within the same module system. That will enable you to have those libraries compiled for the specific MPI version (OpenMPI 3) and the specific compiler (GNU - gfortran) even if you have several of these concurrently.

Then I have this in my `.bashrc.`

```
module load gnu
module load openmpi
module load netcdf-fortran
module load pfftw3
module load phdf5
module load pnetcdf
```